# Center float except last row

Tags: php, jquery, css, css-float

I need to center some floated divs inside a container. The code I'm using works but I need the last row of floated elements to be aligned to the left and not centered. It's a photo album and all the thumbnails are automatically generated by a gallery script.

[This is what the code produces](http://i48.tinypic.com/34855w4.jpg)

[This is what I need](http://i45.tinypic.com/i4pbtu.jpg)

I don't think this is possible with css alone, maybe some jquery or php...

**CSS**

```
#gallery {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #999999;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    width: 750px;
}

.image {*display:inline;
    background: #F7F9FD;
    border: 1px solid #E7F0F5;
    display: -moz-inline-stack;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 100%;
    margin: 1em;
    padding: 0;
    text-align:left;vertical-align:top;
    zoom:1;
}

.imagethumb a, .imagethumb a:hover {
    border:0;
    display: block;
    margin: 5px;
}

.imagethumb {float: left;}

.clear {clear: both}
```

**The PHP code**

```
<div id="gallery">
<?php while (next_image(false, $firstPageImages)): ?>
<div class="image">
<div class="imagethumb">
<a href="<?php echo htmlspecialchars(getImageLinkURL());?>" title="<?php echo getBareImageTitle();?>"><?php printImageThumb(getAnnotatedImageTitle()); ?></a>
</div>
</div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</div>
```

**Generated html**

```
<div id="gallery">

<div id="images">

<div class="image">
<div class="imagethumb"><a href="/zen/p101-01.jpg.php" title="p101-01"><img src="/zen/cache/p101-01_110_thumb.jpg" alt="p101-01" /></a></div>
</div>
<div class="image">
<div class="imagethumb"><a href="/zen/p101-02.jpg.php" title="p101-02"><img src="/zen/cache/p101-02_110_thumb.jpg" alt="p101-02" /></a></div>
</div>
<div class="image">
<div class="imagethumb"><a href="/zen/p101-04.jpg.php" title="p101-04"><img src="/zen/cache/p101-04_110_thumb.jpg" alt="p101-04" /></a></div>
</div>
[...]
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just align left the whole thing with a left-padding and achieve the same result.

Or, you could align left everything and place it in another div container that is centered.

Comment: I think this is the best solution (#2) -- 

Add an internal wrap:
`<div id="gallery"><div id="gallery_wrap">`

Add the css `#gallery_wrap {text-align: left; width: 700px; margin: 0 auto;}` and that -should- approximate what you're going for (of course the values will need to be tweaked here a bit)

Comment: I'll go with #2. The downside is that you have to specify a size but it's better than nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you are doing with all those nast hacks.. no jquery or php needed. just css.

This works fine for me. I did add widths and heights on the images because I didn't feel like actually getting an image. buts its all the same.

**CSS**

```
#gallery { background-color: #fff; border: 1px solid #999; margin: 0 auto; overflow: hidden; position: relative; text-align: center; width: 750px; }
.imagethumb a, 
.imagethumb a:hover { border:0; display: block; margin: 5px; }
.imagethumb {float: left; margin:5px; background: #F7F9FD; border: 1px solid #E7F0F5; width:100px; height:200px;} 
.clear {clear: both}
```

**HTML Final Output**

```
<div id="gallery">
    <div id="images">
        <div class="imagethumb"><a href="/zen/p101-01.jpg.php" title="p101-01"><img src="/zen/cache/p101-01_110_thumb.jpg" alt="p101-01" /></a></div>
    <div class="imagethumb"><a href="/zen/p101-01.jpg.php" title="p101-01"><img src="/zen/cache/p101-01_110_thumb.jpg" alt="p101-01" /></a></div>
    <div class="imagethumb"><a href="/zen/p101-01.jpg.php" title="p101-01"><img src="/zen/cache/p101-01_110_thumb.jpg" alt="p101-01" /></a></div>
    <div class="imagethumb"><a href="/zen/p101-01.jpg.php" title="p101-01"><img src="/zen/cache/p101-01_110_thumb.jpg" alt="p101-01" /></a></div>
    <div class="imagethumb"><a href="/zen/p101-01.jpg.php" title="p101-01"><img src="/zen/cache/p101-01_110_thumb.jpg" alt="p101-01" /></a></div>
    <div class="imagethumb"><a href="/zen/p101-01.jpg.php" title="p101-01"><img src="/zen/cache/p101-01_110_thumb.jpg" alt="p101-01" /></a></div>
    <div class="imagethumb"><a href="/zen/p101-01.jpg.php" title="p101-01"><img src="/zen/cache/p101-01_110_thumb.jpg" alt="p101-01" /></a></div>
    <div class="imagethumb"><a href="/zen/p101-01.jpg.php" title="p101-01"><img src="/zen/cache/p101-01_110_thumb.jpg" alt="p101-01" /></a></div>
    <div class="imagethumb"><a href="/zen/p101-01.jpg.php" title="p101-01"><img src="/zen/cache/p101-01_110_thumb.jpg" alt="p101-01" /></a></div>
    <div class="imagethumb"><a href="/zen/p101-01.jpg.php" title="p101-01"><img src="/zen/cache/p101-01_110_thumb.jpg" alt="p101-01" /></a></div>
    </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```